# three.js drag multi objects

Tags: javascript, three.js

I made an 3D space with Three.js like in this example http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_interactive_draggablecubes.html

The next target is to enable user to select and drag/move multiple objects at a time.

I wonder if the enhancement of current implementation of the example can make it that way or I need a different implementation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you managed to do that?  I want that function too :D

Answer (score 2):

You could use the bounding box of each object that you're selecting, then raycast a cube that matches that combined bounding box, move that big box and apply the position change to the selected objects.

Comment: Also dragging the mouse could size the bounding box in all directions.

Comment: BTW, if you have any example/demo available, I would appreciate it.